# Basic authorization performance at Websphere 7 larg LDAP AD

Tags: performance, active-directory, ldap, websphere, basic-authentication

I have got Websphere7 with large MS Active Directory (5 subdomains, OU's are not structured right).
Problem is that basic authorization (with ad user) takes too long time (from 10 sec to 1 min). Then that login is cached, and works fast.

my WAS security is federated, consist of default File based and ldap.
ldap repository settings are default, except:
'Support referrals to other LDAP servers' - 'Follow'

I tried to create local (File based user) and use it to secure application, unfortunately, it tokes too long time too.

How to deal with that?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting ADAM in front of your real LDAP, or accessing the global catalog port on your MSAD? Both are supposed to help with the referral chasing delays.

Answer (score 0):

The reason a file based user takes the same amount of time is because both the file based and ldap repositories are searched when a user is authenticated.

Narrow the user search base as much as possible. This can be done on the admin console under `Global security > Federated repositories > [AD_LDAP] > Federated repositories entity types to LDAP object classes mapping > PersonAccount`

You will need to know where all the users are that can be authenticated, and take the highest RDN possible of your tree, eg. cn=users,dc=company,dc=com. If this field is blank, the entire LDAP tree is searched.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, users accounts located in multiple 'random' OUs.

Comment: Try running an ldapsearch for a user. See if this takes 10-60 seconds as well. It sounds like you may need to do something on the LDAP side.